# Read socket after closing read side?

Tags: sockets, shutdown

I am a server. I am reading data from a socket. I read something bad from the socket that makes me want to drop the connection, but I don't want to lose incoming data that is "already in the pipe". I need to tell the sender to stop sending because I'm about to drop the connection and anything he puts on the wire will be lost when I close the socket.

What do I do? Do I issue `shutdown(socket, SHUT_RD)`? If I do, will this tell the sender to stop sending yet allow me to continue to read the socket until all data is drained?

---

The application is something which is supposed to never lose data.

The server is written in Java, and I'm not the developer. I am making recommendations to him so that the data I am sending him will never get lost. I'm developing the client (Node.js) which doesn't have fine control over the sockets API.

I had to hand write HTTP pipeline because Node.js doesn't do that. This is where the client just keeps sending HTTP down the connection and doesn't wait for the response before sending the next request. The client sends about 30k QPS.

I had a scheme where I queued up requests in a FIFO queue, then removed them when the response came back. If the connection dropped, I would replay any requests that had not been acknowledged however this ends up playing "The Bad" request also and the connection just gets dropped again, and again, and again.

I seem to recall reading something that starts with:

> Those who attempt to rewrite TCP are doomed...

So I thought I would just scrap my complicated system and see if TCP can give me what I need. It's all Linux environment.

The Java developer is fronting his application with Nginx and Nginx is what is dropping the connection without doing a shutdown, just closes the connection hard.

Anyway, the point is, to make my client fault tolerant, I'd like to be responsible for minimizing data loss no matter what the other end does. Keeping a queue of unacked requests and replaying them if necessary would work but it's not as simple as it seems (note the "replay the bad transaction" problem which I didn't anticipate as an example, and it also causes double data which in this case is ok but in general is probably not).

There are other reasons the server would terminate the connection. It does so now and then to make the client do a DNS lookup (they may want to change the ip address of the server on-the-fly) or there may just be a network glitch which breaks the connection.

Comment: What language are you running this with? What data do you want to keep? Are you using async sockets?

Comment: @A.Abramov What difference does the language or aysnc make?

Comment: @EJP The language, so I'll know how to give him examples. The async is not only a different syntax, but a whole different concept - You might be able to read data from the current read while closing the async connection, and that could be important.

Comment: Can your server send back an error-response to the client so that the client will know which request was "the bad request", and therefore know not to send it again?

Comment: Why are you sending bad transactions? That's the real problem here. Neither end needs to be fault-tolerant of coding bugs.

Answer (score 2):

> I am a server. I am reading data from a socket. I read something bad from the socket that makes me want to drop the connection, but I don't want to lose incoming data that is "already in the pipe".

Why not? You read 'something bad': what makes you think there is anything good afterwards? or that you can correctly re-synchronize to it? after skipping some unknown number of bad bytes to get to the start of the next message?

> I need to tell the sender to stop sending because I'm about to drop the connection and anything he puts on the wire will be lost when I close the socket. Do I issue `shutdown(socket, SHUT_RD)`? If I do, will this tell the sender to stop sending

This is highly platform-dependent, depending on the server platform:

- Windows will issue an RST which eventually gives the sender a 'connection reset'.
- BSD-based Unixes will accept and ignore the data (i.e. ACK it but throw it away, rather than entering it into your socket receive buffer), so the sender will just keep sending as much as he likes, until you close the socket, when he will either read an end-of-stream or get a 'connection reset' on write.
- Linux will accept the data until your socket send buffer fills up; then your receive window will close, which blocks the sender; then when you close the socket the sender will get a 'connection reset'.

> yet allow me to continue to read the socket until all data is drained?

It may or may not let you read all the data that has already arrived. For example Windows gives you a `SocketException: Socket input is shutdown` immediately you read after the shutdown. You shouldn't receive any data that was in flight at the moment you issued the shutdown.

Strange requirement. I would just drop the connection.